# What is a regular expression for the format of these MAC Address?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, mac-address

Format as below:

- 0060.9f9f.b990
- 00af.1fc0.3e6d

I'm working on the visual studio validation check, I have tons of mac address and I'm trying to find a regular expression fits all these mac address as the format shown.

Comment: Those look like two MAC addresses to me, not one. Which of them do you want to match?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does the input look like? What technology are you working with?

Comment: Have you tried any regular expression? If yes, what didn't work as expected; if no, what are you stuck on?

Comment: I'm working on the visual studio validation check, I have tons of mac address and I'm trying to find a regular expression fits all these mac address shows format before.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex:

```
^([0-9a-f]{4}\.[0-9a-f]{4}\.[0-9a-f]{4})$
```

For more, checkout this link:

[Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=mac%20address)